# PyTorch installation on Ubuntu 16.04 (CPU)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, conda, pytorch

I want to install `pytorch-cpu` and `torch-vision-cpu` on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine using conda.

I followed the instructions specified in [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/).

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

I'm getting the following error report.

```
ninja-1.8.2          |  1.3 MB | ####################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed


ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

**Environment info**

```
  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
          COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/thechain/anaconda3
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/thechain/anaconda3/bin:/home/thechain/anaconda3/bin:/home/thecha
                          in/gems/bin:/home/thechain/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/home/thechain/gems/bi
                          n:/home/thechain/bin:/home/thechain/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lo
                          cal/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/sna
                          p/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
            XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
         XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0

     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/thechain/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : /home/thechain/anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /home/thechain/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/thechain/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/thechain/.conda/envs
                          /home/thechain/anaconda3/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Linux/4.13.0-36-generic ubuntu/16.04 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

> sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/anaconda3